# Найти товары с помощью оператора JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null

Нужно за семь последних дней и предпоследних семь дней начиная с текущей даты для каждого товара вывести сумму, на которую он был продан (умножить количество товара на его цену). У меня есть таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На рисунке показано, как они связаны между собой. 
Вот мой код:

```
SELECT p.name, s1.y, s2.y FROM
(SELECT p1.name as x, (pl1.price * sp1.quantity) as y, sp1.sid as z FROM 
products p1, pricelist pl1, salemap sp1
WHERE p1.prod_id = pl1.prod_id AND
  pl1.dat = sp1.dat AND
  to_date(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') - to_date(sp1.sale_dat, 'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN 0 and 7) s1, 
(SELECT p2.name as x, (pl2.price * sp2.quantity) as y, sp2.sid as z FROM products p2, pricelist pl2, salemap sp2
WHERE p2.prod_id = pl2.prod_id AND
  pl2.dat = sp2.dat AND
  to_date(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') - to_date(sp2.sale_dat, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
BETWEEN 8 and 14) s2, 
products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND
      pl.dat = sp.dat
```

В данном случае у меня sale_dat это дата продажи товара, 
p.name - это имя товара.
Мне нужно в первой колонке написать имя всех товаров, во второй колонке цену товаров умноженную на количество проданных товаров только там, где товары были проданы за последнюю неделю. Во всех остальных ячейках должен быть null.
В третьей колонке написать цену товаров умноженную на их количество только там, где они были проданы за предпоследнюю неделю. В остальных ячейках - null. 
Нужно это сделать с помощью оператора JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связка через inner join будет такая

```
Select  p.name  from product p
    Inner join pricelist pl on p.prod_id=pl.prod_id
    Inner join salemap sm on pl.prod_id=sm.prod_id
```

все расчеты не изменяться, изменяться только псевдонимы по таблицам p - Products pl - PriceList sm - SaleMap пример для демонстрации inner join.